# Should completely correct answers be downvoted only because they may have repeated certain points in earlier answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes

When an answer to a question, which was asked years ago, is given, the answer is of good quality and completely correct, but it may have repeated certain points already mentioned in earlier answers, should such answers be down voted?

Comment: I personally downvote late answers when they add no new information whatsoever, but there is no such rule that you should. Vote as you please.

Comment: There are no hard rules about what "should" or "shouldn't" be up-voted or down-voted.

Comment: I think only wrong answers and below quality answers and question should be downvoted, downvoting correct answers just because it is late answer is weird.

Comment: For me, it depends on how the points are repeated. If it is a more or less 1:1 copy of the text/code of a previous answer I'd downvote. If it just covers the same things than it's fine for me

Comment: It can depend. The worst case scenario is plagiarism of other good answers -- That has entire questions dedicated to how we deal with plagiarism. A better case is someone who was writing at the same time, and a couple minutes before another person posted a similar answer, probably because they didn't see the other post until they hit submit on their own answer. In those cases, I either upvote the better written one or upvote both, but that's personal preference. There are more circumstances, and each one is different, so it would be hard to make a "Do this always" answer.

Comment: @BDL I completely agree with you, when there is no 1:1 copy and no evidence of wilful plagiarism, downvoting of answers is wrong.

Comment: @Suraj, What part of Glorfindel's answer do you disagree with? If readers find your answer _not useful_, they are free to vote as they please.

Comment: I personally downvote answers that don't provide anything new.  That easily meets the criteria for uselessness; people have to read and judge your new answer, and not adding anything new just wastes everyone's time.

Comment: Repeating points in other answers isn't a problem,  as long as your answer also brings something new to the table. If your answer is just rehashing other answers (with different words), then yes it isn't useful. The fact that it's correct doesn't mean it is useful since the information  is already on the page.

Answer (score 20):

If it doesn't add *any* value (because it *only* repeats points already mentioned in earlier answers), it is not really useful, is it? Well, that's exactly what the downvote tooltip says:

> This answer is not useful

Different people may have different opinions on what is 'useful' and what not; that's why we are allowed to vote or not to vote as we please (with a few limitations, but those do not apply here).

Of course, new answers which combine points already mentioned in earlier answers in a well-structured manner could be useful and may deserve to be upvoted. But this is not the case in the answer you're probably worried about. I won't link it here, because of the [Meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235225/295232), but I agree with Servy's comments there.